Scale Latex Table to Page Width
I created a table:
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}

{\rowcolors{2}{gray!10!white!100}{gray!25!white!100}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2.75cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{1.5cm}p{2.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table} \\
    \hline
    & \textbf{A} & B & C & D & E & F & G \\
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
     &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
     &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}

The table is too wide. I would like to scale it to page width without adjusting the column width and without creating line breaks. Is that possible?

Welcome! Scaling tables to fit is typographically evil ;). You end up with arbitrary font sizes, which don't match those in the rest of the document, and inconsistent line widths and spacings. Moreover, scaling will (obviously) alter the column widths anyway. Please consider an alternative method such as tabularx.

@cfr can't I adjust the font size?

Yes. You could say e.g. {\small\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}\par} but that won't help if your table is currently too wide because your column widths are specified in cm and aren't relative to font size. Or do the columns fit but the material is too wide for the columns? Then \small should help.

Could you make your code so we can compile it? See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228. Your paper size and page layout are obviously crucial here.

Welcome. // As already mentioned have a look into the tabularx manual (https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). E.g. ch. 2 shows examples of using X columns for your benefit. It will easy your typesetting, and especially free you from tweaking fonts: Latex it's not Word or similar.

A good and easy option for this  is tabulary that set automatically the width of L,C,R and J columns up to fill the maximal width (but only when really needed, otherwise will make a table narrower):

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
{\rowcolors{4}{gray!10!white!100}{gray!25!white!100}
\tymax=.75\linewidth
\tymin=.25\linewidth
\footnotesize\sffamily
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{lLCRJcc}\specialrule{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Table}\\\specialrule{1.6pt}{0pt}{0pt}
    \textbf{Foo} & L     & C               & R               & J               \\\specialrule{.8pt}{0pt}{0pt}
    foo & \lipsum[1][1]  & \lipsum[2][1]   & \lipsum[3][1]   & \lipsum[4][1]   \\
    foo & \lipsum[1][2]  & \lipsum[2][2]   & \lipsum[3][2]   & \lipsum[4][2-3] \\
    foo & \lipsum[1][3]  & \lipsum[2][3]   & \lipsum[3][3]   & \lipsum[4][3]   \\
    foo & \lipsum[1][4]  & \lipsum[2][5]   & \lipsum[3][4]   & \lipsum[4][4]   \\\specialrule{1.6pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\end{tabulary}}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{document}

A similar option is the commented tabular X, that distribute equally all the available space among the  X columns (it should be at least one). This could be more convenient when (1) you need columns of equal widths and (2) when content is not enough to fill the text width but you you want tables from left to right margin at any cost (that is a bad idea). Tabulary is better when you have a lot of content that need unequal columns and/or when you do not want the default left align. Run texdoc tabularx for more information.
Once you know both packages, take also a look to tabular array and to oter packages to make tables.
